# Docker Volume name with slash's (/) unable to be removed

Tags: docker, docker-volume

In short, I wasn't paying attention to what I was doing and created a Docker volume named `/etc/[folder name]`, using the [`local-persist`](https://github.com/MatchbookLab/local-persist) storage driver (*Note: I was not trying to create a volume in `/etc` on the host, long story, but it was just a typo*). Obviously this was not intentional, so in going to remove it, I get the message: `Error: No such volume: /etc/[folder name]`.

Output of `docker volume ls`:

```
carsons5@host:~$ docker volume ls
DRIVER          VOLUME NAME
local-persist   /etc/[folder name]
local-persist   ...
local-persist   ...
local-persist   ...
local-persist   ...
local           ...
```

The commands and troubleshooting steps I took are as follows:

- Remove with quotes (`docker volume rm "/etc/[folder name]"`)
- Remove with escape sequences (`docker volume rm \/etc\/[folder name]`)
- Remove with prune (`docker volume prune`/`docker volume prune --force`)
- Create a container using the volume (did not work: `Error: No such volume: /etc/[folder name]`)

At this point, I feel like I am about out of options and was wondering if anyone else had experienced this. Additionally, is there still any point/benefit to using the `local-persist` driver? I have been using it for years, but troubleshooting this problem made me realize there may be an alternative built in to Docker itself.

Other details:

```
Host OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 Server
Docker Version: 20.10.8
```

Comment: `I have been using it for years, but troubleshooting this problem made me realize there may be an alternative built in to Docker itself.` To share a specific directory with a docker container, I normally use [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

Comment: @NickODell How do you do this with custom volume drivers?